# nexus 7 Linux kernel : What file to fiddle with for volume control hacking ?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to make a simple system call that will be called by a LKM that will increase the volume on my nexus 7 (tegra based) when I press the up arrow and decrease it with the down key. Simple project to get the ball rolling for bigger hacking.

My question is how to localize files which handle these natively for android. I searched in sound/  drivers/  and also arch/arm/mach-tegra/   . With so many different versions of firmware for different hardware in the source is there a way to easily localize what files are pertinent to you. For example when I press the volume keys on my nexus and do a dmsg on the shell , I see a printk something like " gpio : KEY_VOLUMEUP". I was trying to find this printk for a start.

Any help on this problem as well as larger tips on kernel hacking will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For nexus 7, the audio driver is [not proprietary](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#grouper) , which means that you should be able to search for the printk. Have you tried `grep -rs 'gpio : KEY_VOLUMEUP' .` in the whole kernel source code tree? That is usually my best bet.

Kernel hacking tips, read the LDD3 book online: http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Answer (score 0):

"gpio : KEY_VOLUMEUP" is a message from the GPIO driver which reacts to the volume key connected to an input pin and emulates a keyboard (KEY_VOLUMEUP is a key code). One way to increase the volume from an LKM is to write a keyboard driver and send KEY_VOLUMEUP events. There are plenty of various keyboard drivers in the Linux kernel that can be used as an example.